# Why does my SQL workspace only load in incognito mode?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have recently started using BigQuery as part of the Google Data Analytics course in coursera. When I try to load the BigQuery console, it keeps showing the loading icon but never fully loads. However, when I sig in in incognito mode I have no issues. Do you know what can be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try on a different browser? Clear caching your browser might help also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Nestor. I tried clearing the cookies and so on of my browser, but it still does not work. It does work, however, in a different browser. I just find it very odd that it does not work in regular Chrome, considering it is a Google product.

Comment: That is odd, I assume you have tried restarting your device? Can you try signing out then sign back at your Google chrome profile ? if everything else fails try re-installing your browser. (You can also inspect the network activity when going to BQ by opening the source(right click then click inspect) then select the network. For reference: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/)

Comment: Thanks, Nestor. I tried both restarting my device and signing out and back in, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: However, the inspect option was very useful. There was an error regarding the AdBlock that made the page crash constantly. Once I disabled it on this website, it works just fine.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good! No problem at all. I will post this as an answer, as it might be helpful to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requested to do basic troubleshooting: Restart Browser, Clear cache, Sign in and sign out of the browser etc etc.

Solution that **worked**: Inspected the source of the page when accessing BQ as there was an error in **AdBlock**. So disabling AdBlock in Google Chrome is a possible solution when running into this kind of problem.